# ERROR: Label "foo" used but not defined

Tags: c++, function, label, goto

So I was fooling around with some C++ and got the previously stated error with some code that looked kind of like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char foodstuffs;

void fruit()
{
cin>>foodstuffs;
switch(foodstuffs)
{
case 'a': goto foo; break;
case 'b': goto fooo; break;
}
}

int main()
{
cout<<"What do you want to eat? (a/b)";
fruit();
foo: cout<<"You eat an apple.";
fooo: cout<<"You eat a banana.";
}
```

The exact code was much more complex, but this is just to show you the error I got.

Now I realize that everyone despises the "goto" statement for some reason, but my actual code is full of so many gotos that I don't really have the time/patience to go back and change them all. Also, I'm kind of a novice programmer and I find gotos and labels to be very easy to use.

My question is how can I predefine these labels so that the function fruit() knows what they are? Also, I need to do this without moving the labels out of the main function.

Comment: You find the gotos and labels easy to use, but extremely hard to go back and change. That, my friend, is why everyone hates them.

Comment: why goto? as chris said, everyone hates them ;)

Comment: The main point is, you've seen how they can make code hard to read, follow, understand, and maintain. There are a couple valid uses where `goto` arguably makes code cleaner, and I personally wouldn't penalize `goto` if the resulting code was cleaner, but it's definitely not something to be thrown in on a whim.

Comment: Perhaps the reason you like goto is that you haven't learned C++ yet. Look up the "return" keyword as your next lesson. BTW - you might want to fix the bug in your example where eating an apple also eats a banana.

Comment: @chris Goto, like "return" and "break" and "continue" is just a flow control construct. The chaos begins when you start using it across object and variable definition scopes, etc, and when you use it instead of the better named and more clearly explanatory alternatives. Take the OPs example code. "return" would have made it a lot easier to read the program as a whole. Instead, a foodstuff is pulled from cin and a goto is performed to foo or fooo, none of which is explanatory. *shrug*

Comment: @kfsone, Exactly, there are valid uses, but these are not.

Comment: I appreciate the insight, but none of this really helps me with jumping between functions.

Comment: @UrameshiYusuke That's because you can't do that. You need to help yourself by learning not to use `goto`.

Comment: If I could I would downvote all the people who instead of answering the question are arguing about whether to use goto or not. And this is not enough: they also downvote the question. Hello: the question was not whether using goto is good or not.

Answer (score 9):

The `goto` statement can only go to locally defined labels, it can't jump to other functions.

So the labels in `main` will not be referenced, and the `goto` statements in `fruit` will not find the labels.

Comment: What can I use to jump to other functions then?

Comment: @UrameshiYusuke don't jump to other functions. Just return to the point of call.

Comment: @UrameshiYusuke My advice is: **don't!** If you need to jump between functions your design is most likely flawed. Instead `return` from the function with a special value, then use `if` or `switch` on that returned value in the caller to do different things. Using `goto` can be useful in some _very limited_ situations, but for most uses there are always other and better solutions.

Answer (score 4):

What you are *trying* to do - jump between functions - is not valid for a whole slew of reasons, not least being object scope and life time, consider:

```
void foo()
{
    if(feelLikeIt)
       goto foobar;
}

void bar()
{
    std::string message = "Hello";
foobar:
    cout << message << endl;
}
```

Jumping to foobar from foo is illegal because "message" won't exist.

So the language just plain doesn't let you do this.

Further, the way you are trying to use "goto" would prevent you from re-using the "fruit()" function because it always makes a decision about what to do with the selection rather than the function calling it. What if you wanted to do this:

```
cout<<"What do you want to eat? (a/b)";
fruit();
foo: cout<<"You eat an apple.";
fooo: cout<<"You eat a banana.";
cout<<"What does your friend want to eat? (a/b)";
fruit();
// oops, you just created a loop because fruit made the decision on what to do next.
```

What you ACTUALLY want to do is use "fruit()" as a function that returns a value.

```
enum Fruit { NoSuchFruit, Apple, Banana };

Fruit fruit(const char* request)
{
    char foodstuffs;
    cout << request << " (a/b)";
    cin >> foodstuffs;
    switch (foodstuffs)
    {
        case 'a': return Apple;
        case 'b': return Banana;
        default:
            cout << "Don't recognize that fruit (" << foodstuffs << ")." << endl;
            return NoSuchFruit;
    }
}

const char* fruitNames[] = { "nothing", "an apple" ,"a banana" };

int main()
{
    Fruit eaten = fruit("What do you want to eat?");
    cout << "You ate " << fruitNames[eaten] << "." << endl;
    eaten = fruit("What does your friend want to eat?");
    cout << "Your friend ate " << fruitNames[eaten] << "." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. You cannot `goto` to a label that is outside of the current executing function. Also, there are other limits on the uses of `goto`. For example, you cannot skip a variable definition using `goto`. And there are others that I am not fully aware of.

The bottom line?

## Don't use `goto`.

Comment: It's good in assembly, I think, and can be a nice similarity.

Comment: The question was not whether to use it or not but HOW.

Answer (score 0):

`goto` cannot be used to navigate outside the current function. Try returning something from the function and use that in if else condition.